# Android: Layouts not being added below each other

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to add multiple ConstraintLayouts below each other. But they appear to be on the same position. (See picture).

**Question**: How do I get the ConstraintLayouts to be below each other?

What's happpening right now:

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

How it should look like:

[image]

Activity.java

```
String response = (String) databaseManager.execute(phpLocation,  parameters).get();
        List<Review> listOfReviews = (List<Review>) EntityConverter.getInstance().jsonToObject(response,
                new TypeToken<Collection<Review>>(){}.getType());

        int totalscore = 0;
        int amountOfReviews = 0;

        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutReviews = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutReviews);
        for(Review r : listOfReviews) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.reviewtemplate, null);
            v.setId(amountOfReviews);

            TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewReviewName);
            name.setText(r.getName());

            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarReviewScore);
            ratingBar.setRating(r.getScore());
            totalscore += r.getScore();

            TextView ratingText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewReviewText);
            ratingText.setText(r.getReviewtext());

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            if (amountOfReviews != 0) {
                // add the rule that places your button below your EditText object
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, v.getId() -1);
            }

            relativeLayoutReviews.addView(v, amountOfReviews);
            amountOfReviews++;
        }
```

reviewtemplate.xml (The thing which I'm trying to insert)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/reviewTemplate"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewReviewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Pietje"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBarReviewScore"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewReviewName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewReviewText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingBarReviewScore" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

RelativeLayout which will contain all the reviews.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutReviews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the root (parent) layout is RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Child views added into a RelativeLayout do not position one after another because their parent lays out their positioning depending on their child attributes (hence why the positioning is relative).

Add them into a LinearLayout with vertical orientation instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a LinearLayout for your Layout Reviews, with a orientation vertical.

EDIT:

Use [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) attibute

Can you try ?

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutReviews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" > 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it with ConstraintLayouts?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think chaining is part of CoordinatorLayout, and you put it between RelativeLayout tags.

Comment: I can't try for now but you sloud be able to use this attribute in you relative layout.

Comment: I tried but I'm getting the error that "chain_spread" is not a known symbol.

Comment: I tried to use "spead", and I got no compile errors anymore. But the CoordinatorLayouts are still on the same position unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your issue, which text views are at the same position ?

Comment: Thank you, you should try with a Linear layout instead of your relative so